# getProductId from an order

Tags: php, magento, product, ecommerce-sales

I am new to Magento, so I am really confused. I need some help with the following: I am  trying to make a script wherein I can see all the orders from a particular status of Magento of a `timesperiod`. This script should mail me everyday how many products I sold, so I can know how many orders I have to place. I count them manual now for each product

In the generated e-mail I would only like to have product name , product id, amount.

I currently have the following code:

```
$content = '';
$yesterday = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("-1 day"));
$orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()
->addFieldToFilter('status', Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_PROCESSING)
->addAttributeToFilter('created_at', array('from'  => $yesterday));

foreach($orders as $order) {
 //this does not work
    $productId = $order->getProductId();

}
```

Can anyone help me to get the product id from the orders? So I can get the product name from the product class. I also need the `productId` to group the elements to get the total orders of a product. I did not group it yet, because I did not manage to retrieve the product Id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
...
foreach($orders as $order) {
   //this does not work
   $items = $order->getAllItems();  //$order->getAllVisibleItems() 
   foreach($items as $item){
     $productId = $item->getProductId();
   }

}
```

Take a look @ http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/18629/